# Is it possible to use only one field to index traditional and simplified Chinese?

Tags: solr, lucene

[Official Solr documentation](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/language-analysis.html#LanguageAnalysis-SimplifiedChinese) points to the separation of Simplified and Traditional Chinese by using different Tokenizers. I wonder if people use [ICU Transform Filter](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/filter-descriptions.html#FilterDescriptions-ICUTransformFilter) to Traditional <-> Simplified conversion and then be able to have one unique field for both Chineses.

At the same time, it seems that this conversion is a really hard task and it doesn't seem to be [solved](http://www.kanji.org/cjk/c2c/c2cbasis.htm).

The simple question is what is the recommended way of indexing traditional and simplified Chinese in Solr? It would be really convenient to have a unique field for both, but I couldn't find a good success case for that.

Comment: What's the reason for not using different fields? You can use `qf` with edismax to search both fields at the same time, having different analysis and tokenization for each field.

Comment: @MatsLindh My system was designed to understand "zh" (chinese) as a whole - not zh-cn, zh-tw. So it is just a matter of keep consistency. But of course I won't sacrifice the search/index quality because of that. I was just wondering if it's possible and if worth using it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The truth is, it is possible. This [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MQ6WtBw8T_U) shows how you could create an field with as many languages as possible. But looks tricky.